# Bot should say /userinfo @name and show user info but doesnt do that

Tags: bots, discord

my bot should say /userinfo @name when someone joins my server and it gives me the details. the bot says it but there is no reaction on the second command please help

```html
bot.on('ready', () => console.log("online!"));

bot.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
    let guild = member.guild;
    let memberTag = member.user.tag;
    if(guild.systemChannel){
        guild.systemChannel.send("/userinfo" +"<@" + member.id + ">" )
    }

});




bot.on('message', async (msg) => {

if (msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "userinfo")) {
    let member = msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.author;
    let userembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor(msg.guild.member(member).highestRole.color)
        .setThumbnail(member.displayAvatarURL)
        
        .setTitle(`Here is ${member.username}'s info.`)
        .addField(`Name:`, member.username, true)
        .addField(`Id:`, member.id, true)
        .addField(`Bot:`, member.bot ? "Yes" : "No", true)
        .addField("Game:", msg.guild.member(member).presence.game ? msg.guild.member(member).presence.game.name : "Not Playing", true)
        .addField("Nickname:", msg.guild.member(member).nickname ? msg.guild.member(member).nickname : "None", true )
        .addField("Last Messsage:", member.lastMessage, true)
        .addField(`Roles:`, msg.guild.member(member).roles.map(s => s).join(" | "), true)
        .addField("Created At:", member.createdAt, true)
        .addField("JoinedAt:", msg.guild.member(member).joinedAt, true)
        msg.channel.send(userembed);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not sending because `.systemChannel` is read only, [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=systemChannel) . There `.defaultChannel` in D.js has also been deprecated, so you could use something like `member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "channel-name");` however if there was no channel with that name, then it wouldn't send it. Although there is a little workaround for this that finds the "default channel" which is basically working out the first channel the bot can send messages in, but obviously if it has admin then this could be in a channel where you don't want it to send messages, so watch out for that, it will also check if there is a channel called "general" and use that if there is, you can find this guide [here](http://anidiots.guide/frequently-asked-questions#channels-and-guilds).

Comment: it says ReferenceError: message is not defined. and do you mean like this if(member.guild.channels.find(channel => channel.name === "welcomechannel"));
   guild.systemChannel.send("/userinfo" + " <@" + member.id + ">" )                                              this way it gives an error (node:6868) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty.

Comment: to say it easyer the bot says in chat 
JoJoBOTvandaag om 22:16
/userinfo @Vexxed  but no reactuon on the command it should trigger the second /userinfo command but instead i get  RangeError: RichEmbed field values may not be empty